# Failure to deploy Nuxt application to Netlify

Tags: nuxt.js, netlify

I am trying to deploy a Nuxt application and I followed a udemy lecture step by step, theirs worked, but mine is not, any help would be much appreciated.

#### Here's my netlify config:

[image: Netlify Config]

#### And here's my build log

```
Build Log:
7:00:42 PM: Build ready to start
7:00:44 PM: build-image version: d2c6dbeac570350a387d832f64bc980dc964ad65 (focal)
7:00:44 PM: build-image tag: v4.8.0
7:00:44 PM: buildbot version: 17f6c1ab2fe6d61574ce02b038041b816bf6c085
7:00:44 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
7:00:44 PM: Starting to download cache of 676.1KB
7:00:44 PM: Finished downloading cache in 154.455861ms
7:00:44 PM: Starting to extract cache
7:00:44 PM: Finished extracting cache in 13.041304ms
7:00:44 PM: Finished fetching cache in 167.765258ms
7:00:44 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
7:00:45 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
7:00:45 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
7:00:46 PM: Starting build script
7:00:46 PM: Installing dependencies
7:00:46 PM: Python version set to 2.7
7:00:46 PM: Downloading and installing node v16.15.0…
7:00:46 PM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.15.0/node-v16.15.0-linux-x64.tar.xz…
7:00:47 PM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
7:00:47 PM: Checksums matched!
7:00:49 PM: Now using node v16.15.0 (npm v8.5.5)
7:00:49 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
7:00:49 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
7:00:49 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
7:00:50 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.2
7:00:50 PM: Using PHP version 8.0
7:00:50 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
7:00:50 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
7:00:50 PM: go version go1.16.5 linux/amd64
7:00:50 PM: go version go1.16.5 linux/amd64
7:00:50 PM: Installing missing commands
7:00:50 PM: Verify run directory
7:00:52 PM: ​
7:00:52 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:00:52 PM: Netlify Build
7:00:52 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:00:52 PM: ​
7:00:52 PM: ❯ Version
7:00:52 PM: @netlify/build 27.1.3
7:00:52 PM: ​
7:00:52 PM: ❯ Flags
7:00:52 PM: baseRelDir: true
7:00:52 PM: buildId: 628a7a075a97cd0e6a54ecf0
7:00:52 PM: deployId: 628a7a075a97cd0e6a54ecf2
7:00:52 PM: ​
7:00:52 PM: ❯ Current directory
7:00:52 PM: /opt/build/repo
7:00:52 PM: ​
7:00:52 PM: ❯ Config file
7:00:52 PM: No config file was defined: using default values.
7:00:52 PM: ​
7:00:52 PM: ❯ Context
7:00:52 PM: production
7:00:52 PM: ​
7:00:52 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:00:52 PM: 1. Build command from Netlify app
7:00:52 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:00:52 PM: ​
7:00:52 PM: $ npm run generate
7:00:52 PM: npm ERR! code ENOENT
7:00:52 PM: npm ERR! syscall open
7:00:52 PM: npm ERR! path /opt/build/repo/package.json
7:00:52 PM: npm ERR! errno -2
7:00:52 PM: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ‘/opt/build/repo/package.json’
7:00:52 PM: npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
7:00:52 PM: npm ERR! enoent
7:00:52 PM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
7:00:52 PM: npm ERR! /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2022-05-22T18_00_52_303Z-debug-0.log
7:00:52 PM: ​
7:00:52 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:00:52 PM: “build.command” failed
7:00:52 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:00:52 PM: ​
7:00:52 PM: Error message
7:00:52 PM: Command failed with exit code 254: npm run generate (Search results for '"non-zero exit code: 254"' - Netlify Support Forums)
7:00:52 PM: ​
7:00:52 PM: Error location
7:00:52 PM: In Build command from Netlify app:
7:00:52 PM: npm run generate
7:00:52 PM: ​
7:00:52 PM: Resolved config
7:00:52 PM: build:
7:00:52 PM: command: npm run generate
7:00:52 PM: commandOrigin: ui
7:00:52 PM: publish: /opt/build/repo/dist
7:00:52 PM: publishOrigin: ui
7:00:52 PM: Caching artifacts
7:00:52 PM: Started saving build plugins
7:00:53 PM: Finished saving build plugins
7:00:54 PM: Creating deploy upload records
7:00:53 PM: Started saving pip cache
7:00:53 PM: Finished saving pip cache
7:00:53 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
7:00:53 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
7:00:53 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
7:00:53 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
7:00:53 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
7:00:53 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
7:00:53 PM: Started saving rust rustup cache
7:00:54 PM: Failed during stage ‘building site’: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2 (Search results for '"non-zero exit code: 2"' - Netlify Support Forums)
7:00:53 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
7:00:53 PM: Started saving go dependencies
7:00:53 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
7:00:54 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
7:00:54 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
7:00:54 PM: Finished processing build request in 10.392917083s
```

Comment: Some context, configuration or [repro] would be highly welcome here.

Comment: my apologies, I posted this to both the netlify forum and SO, here is the github repo for the project I am attempting to host.

https://github.com/JordanLilley/my-portfolio

Comment: I also added the netlify config to the post

Comment: It now tells me that the error is found 

"In Build command from Netlify app: 
npm run generate"

and the error message is:
Command failed with exit code 254: npm run generate (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-254)

Answer (score 0):

You [didn't set](https://github.com/JordanLilley/my-portfolio/blob/master/my-portfolio-nuxt/nuxt.config.js) a different value for `target`, hence it's taking [the default](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-target#the-target-property), which is `server`.

This value requires a Node.js server to be available for the app to run, hence the need for `npm run build` and a VPS or a platform like Heroku/Digitalocean etc...
If you want to be able to host it statically, you need to set `target: 'static'` and use `npm run generate`.

That allow to a successful build on Netlify as you can [see here](https://radiant-starburst-30aa7c.netlify.app/).